# Convert Integer to Double in MIPS

Tags: assembly, floating-point, integer, double, mips

I want to divide two values that are in `$tn` registers.

I have to divide these two values to get a double result but the function `div` only returns the integer part of that division can anyone help out?

Do i need to convert `$t1` and `$t2` to `$f0` and `$f2`?

How do i do that?

```
li $t1,2 
li $t2,5 

div $f0,$t2,$t1
```

This gives me an error because it expects a `$tn` value not a `$fn` value...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to move and convert the integer stored in a general purpose register to floating point or double register.

Assuming your number is stored in `$a1`, To convert to a double pair (`$f12`, `$f13`) you have to issue:

```
  mtc1.d $a1, $f12
  cvt.d.w $f12, $f12
```

And to convert it to a single precision float (`$f12`) you'd do:

```
  mtc1 $a1, $f12
  cvt.s.w $f12, $f12
```

Then you can use `div.d` or `div.s` to do floating-point division and get a floating point result.

Comment: This reference helped me understand this more https://www.cs.tcd.ie/~waldroj/itral/spim_ref.html